# Erlang ssh_sftp returns eoptions password, what does this error mean?

Tags: ssh, erlang, elixir, sftp

My code is pretty simple right now, I'm calling erlang from elixir.

```
iex> :ssh.start()
iex> :ssh_sftp.start_channel("192.168.1.183", 22, [{:user, "username"}, {:password, "password"}])
```

`:ssh.start()` returns `:ok`, but `:ssh_sftp.start_channel` returns `{:error, {:eoptions, {:password, "password"}}}`. If I remove the password tuple, it then complains about the user tuple. This makes me thing that I'm fundamentally misunderstanding the erlang documentation. I'd like some help understanding what I'm doing wrong. The ssh_sftp documentation is at [ssh_sftp](http://erlang.org/documentation/doc-6.3/lib/ssh-3.1/doc/html/ssh_sftp.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{:eoptions, _}` is returned [when an option passed contains a value of invalid type](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/6a5aa63cbadbc831b38ef7781ca80c759debef44/lib/ssh/src/ssh.erl#L818). You're getting this error because [`:password`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/6a5aa63cbadbc831b38ef7781ca80c759debef44/lib/ssh/src/ssh.erl#L741) must be a list (Erlang String or Elixir charlist). `:user` and the hostname must also be charlists. The following should work:

```
:ssh_sftp.start_channel('192.168.1.183', 22, [{:user, 'username'}, {:password, 'password'}])
```

> This makes me thing that I'm fundamentally misunderstanding the erlang documentation.

Double quoted strings in Erlang are lists of characters, not binaries. If you see double quoted strings in Erlang code, you need to use single quoted strings in Elixir instead.

Comment: So, in the documentation they have `{password, string()}` does this mean that `password` is an atom and `string()` is a single quoted string in Elixir?

Comment: Yes, `password` in Erlang == `:password` in Elixir, and `"foo"` in Erlang == `'foo'` in Elixir. You should check out this guide if you plan to use Erlang libraries from Elixir: http://elixir-lang.org/crash-course.html.